# Cannot get the id of the page I am trying to edit using php

Tags: php

So essentially my issue is that, my website is meant to have an edit function for a selection of artists.

It takes the id of the artist and opens a new page called /editartist.php?id=(id here) with the id changing depending on the artist. However when I try to check if this id is there using `'if(isset($GET['id']))`' in my PHP it doesn't work, I know this because it goes straight to the error this is broken. I need this id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body
<h1 class="title"> Artists </h1>
<div class="nav">
<a href="mainpagehtml.php">Home</a>
<a href="searchpage.php">Artists</a>
<a href="linkhere">Albums</a>
<a href="linkhere">Tracks</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testdb';

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
?>
<?php
if(isset($GET['id']))
{   
    $artistID = fix_string($_GET['id']);
    $sql = ("SELECT artName FROM artist WHERE artID = '$artistID' ");
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param('s', $bound); 
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($bound);
    $result->fetch();
}
else {
    echo "fuck this is broken";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="editartist.php"/>
<?php echo '<input type="text" name="artistname" value= "'.$bound.'">' ?>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php   
if(isset($GET['id'])) {
    $userinput = $_GET['artistName']; 
    $result = $conn->prepare("UPDATE artist SET artName='".$userinput."' WHERE artID='".$artistID."'");
    $result->execute();
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$GET['id']` to `$_GET['id']`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $userinput = $_GET['artistName']; 
    $result = $conn->prepare("UPDATE artist SET artName='".$userinput."' WHERE artID='".$artistID."'");
    $result->execute();
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped so that other visitors can see the working answer faster